# Subprocess Check Output/Run Issue with current directory

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess

When running this from the command line, this works

```
plutil -convert xml1 test.out -o outFile1.xml
```

When running this in python 2.7 I get an error:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output(["plutil -convert xml1 test.out -o outFile1.xml"])
```

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried adding `./` or `.\\` to the directory.

I used `pwd` and `os.getcwd()` to ensure that I am running this from the same directory in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your command up should work; the interpreter might be getting confused with it currently.

```
subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/plutil", "-convert", "xml1", "test", "-o", "outFile1.xml"])
```

Also, you might want to use the absolute path of `plutil` (optional).

Comment: why do I have to split it?